# React Query useQuery() and useState()

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, tanstackreact-query

I have a screen in a React Native app, where I fetch some data using `useQuery` , save this data in a object state with `setState` , then update the state values inside child components. I am stuck at the initialisation of state after the data is fetched. This could have been a lot easier with the now-deprecated `onSuccess`  hook, but I would like to know if there are better alternatives.

I am using `React 18` ,`React Native 0.72`, and `React Query v5`.

I tried the following things:

1. The `select` prop of useQuery:

```
const {refetch, data, isLoading, error} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['leadPreferences'],
    queryFn: async () => getLeadPreferences(setLoggedIn),
    select: (res) => {
      if (res != null) {
        const leadPreferencesData = res.body;
        console.log('running this: ', i++);
        return updateLeadPreferences({
          destinations: [],
          whatsAppContact: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_contact,
          whatsAppCommStatus: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_enabled,
          leadEmail: leadPreferencesData.alert_email_ids,
          emailAlertStatus: leadPreferencesData.email_alert_enabled,
          emailAlertTimes: [],
          leadTypes: leadPreferencesData.lead_types,
          packageTypes: leadPreferencesData.package_types,
          defaultHomePage: leadPreferencesData.landing_page,
        });
      }
    },
  });
```

This throws the `data is undefined` error.

2. `useEffect` method both before and after the useQuery call:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data != undefined) {
      const leadPreferencesData = data.body;
      console.log('running this: ', i++);
      updateLeadPreferences({
        destinations: [],
        whatsAppContact: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_contact,
        whatsAppCommStatus: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_enabled,
        leadEmail: leadPreferencesData.alert_email_ids,
        emailAlertStatus: leadPreferencesData.email_alert_enabled,
        emailAlertTimes: [],
        leadTypes: leadPreferencesData.lead_types,
        packageTypes: leadPreferencesData.package_types,
        defaultHomePage: leadPreferencesData.landing_page,
      });
    }
  },);
```

What should happen:

whenever the value of `data` changes, the state must get updated.
Issues:
Throwing "cannot read properties of undefined" -> if useEffect is called before the useQuery hook
"Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" -> if the useEffect is called after useQuery, with `data` as the dependency array.

3. Calling the `updateLeadPreferences` just before the UI is returned.
   This results in about 51 renders before the debugger throws "too many re-renders" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this once and tell me? (as below)

Use **useQuery** to fetch your data without attempting to set the state directly within the select function. The select option should be purely for selecting or transforming the data you want to use in your component, not for side effects like updating state. Utilize **useEffect** to watch for changes in the data returned by **useQuery** and then update your component's state accordingly.

```
//small example in line with your code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const initialLeadPreferencesState = {
  destinations: [],
  whatsAppContact: '',
  whatsAppCommStatus: false,
  leadEmail: '',
  emailAlertStatus: false,
  emailAlertTimes: [],
  leadTypes: [],
  packageTypes: [],
  defaultHomePage: '',
};

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [leadPreferences, setLeadPreferences] = useState(initialLeadPreferencesState);

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery('leadPreferences', async () => {
    const response = await getLeadPreferences();
    return response.body;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const leadPreferencesData = data;
      setLeadPreferences({
        ...leadPreferences,
        whatsAppContact: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_contact,
        whatsAppCommStatus: leadPreferencesData.whatsapp_enabled,
        leadEmail: leadPreferencesData.alert_email_ids,
        emailAlertStatus: leadPreferencesData.email_alert_enabled,
        leadTypes: leadPreferencesData.lead_types,
        packageTypes: leadPreferencesData.package_types,
        defaultHomePage: leadPreferencesData.landing_page,
      });
    }
  }, [data]); // Dependency array ensures this effect runs only when `data` changes

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>An error occurred</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render your UI here using `leadPreferences` state */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!
However, this still throws the "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error, whenever the API call is first made. When I make a minor change(ie, adding a space), the whole app re-renders, and now the screen is visible, but with the initial state values. As a side effect, when I refetch the data, the screen starts displaying the updated state values.

Comment: hmm... interesting. it's prolly because of the useEffect which is why it renders again. lemme dig in through once again, shall edit my suggestion in that case, soon as I find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Riya, this problem was solved after I moved the whole useEffect code and the UI to another component, and this component is called only when the data is available and is not null.

Comment: I am glad it worked out for you!